# Linux device driver error

Tags: linux, embedded, driver, device

I have an embedded system and I have developed a device driver for a hard disk controller. When I insert the driver using insmod I get the following error.

WARNING: at fs/sysfs/dir.c:455 sysfs_add_one+0xb0/0xdc()
sysfs: cannot create duplicate filename '/block/xsa'

```
Call Trace:
[<c00040ac>] microblaze_unwind+0x54/0x78
[<c0003db8>] show_stack+0x120/0x158
[<c0003df8>] dump_stack+0x8/0x20
[<c000fd40>] warn_slowpath_common+0x80/0xbc
[<c000fe08>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x28/0x40
[<c00d51dc>] sysfs_add_one+0xa4/0xdc
[<c00d5cd4>] create_dir+0x80/0x100
[<c00d5fa0>] sysfs_create_dir+0x138/0x16c
[<c01586cc>] kobject_add_internal+0xc4/0x1dc
[<c0158920>] kobject_add_varg+0x4c/0x78
[<c0158e88>] kobject_add+0x68/0x80
[<c0187420>] device_add+0xac/0x56c
[<c014da98>] register_disk+0x48/0x1b8
[<c014e014>] add_disk+0x110/0x2c8
[<c805c7c4>] bean_of_probe+0x25c/0x324 [bean]
[<c018b9d0>] platform_drv_probe+0xc/0x24
[<c018a2c4>] driver_probe_device+0xe0/0x1b8
[<c018a61c>] __driver_attach+0x68/0xb4
[<c01890d4>] bus_for_each_dev+0x50/0xa8
[<c018a080>] driver_attach+0x18/0x30
[<c0189bac>] bus_add_driver+0xc4/0x2a0
[<c018aad8>] driver_register+0xf0/0x1ac
[<c018bd00>] platform_driver_register+0x58/0x70
[<c805e050>] bean_init+0x50/0xbc [bean]
[<c00002f4>] do_one_initcall+0x11c/0x220
[<c0047504>] sys_init_module+0x84/0x200
SYSCALL
```

---[ end trace 56a543209f1c03c6 ]---
kobject_add_internal failed for xsa with -EEXIST, don't try to register things with the same name in the same directory.
Kernel Stack:

I understand that it is trying to use the name xsa which is already registered to a compact flash card. My question is how does the Kernel decide on the name that should be used? If anyone can help me as I am just starting out with Linux.

Thanks

Jon

Comment: Could you post some code? The answer to this question is very much tied up with the Linux Driver model and its relationship with `sysfs` - some entries are created automatically  - and it might be this that is going wrong.

Comment: Might you have copied fro this "xs" driver when you created yours? Generally, the name of the driver is part of the meta-data handoff when the driver is linked into the kernel. Also, what kernel version and distro are you using?

Comment: I found this line of code in my driver. snprintf(bean->gd->disk_name, 32, "xs%c", bean->id + 'a'); I used another driver to create my own and I am just wondering if the "xs%c" is what the problem is? That line is the only place in my driver code that I can find reference to "xs"